# Using analog comparators to get 2 different outputs depending on the input

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, analog, design, comparator

I am trying to use analog comparators to get two different output voltages, 6V out when the input voltage is -8.5V <= Vin <= -2V and -3V out when the input voltage is -2V < Vin <= 9.5V. I read online about window comparators, but I'm unsure about how I can use them in a situation like this where you have two windows. I tried using two window comparators for the two different windows of input voltages, but that ends up giving me two outputs. I've also tried connecting the output of the first window comparator to the second window comparator but that doesn't really seem to help since the first window comparator essentially becomes useless. Additionally, I am only allowed to use +15V, 0V, and -15V for my rail voltages and not allowed to add any resistors to the rail voltages to alter them. So, my concern is how can I get the 6V and -3V outputs when I can only have the +15,-15, and 0V rail voltages? My understanding is that the output of the analog comparator swings to either +Vcc or -Vcc depending on how your comparator is configured (inverting or non-inverting). I am also wondering how I could set up my circuit using only analog comparators, voltage followers and resistors (since I have a constraint of dissipated power of less than 1 mW without counting the comparators and voltage followers) to fit the aforementioned constraints?
Thanks a lot.
[image: Input/Output plot]

Comment: what do you mean you can't use resistors? Can you use resistors to make voltage dividers on the output? And no, if you have to produce those outputs specifically for those intervals and from +-15V supply, it's impossible from the start without adding any components

Comment: So, what's the problem with 2 outputs? What output are you supposed to get when Vin is <-8.5V or >9.5V? Comparator always outputs one of the two states, it can't output "nothing" or "zero" (unless one of the supply rails is 0 of course)

Comment: When I say I can't use resistors, I meant I can't use them to change the rail supplies to what I want (ideally, 6V and -3V). It needs to stay as +15V,-15V or 0 V. The positive and negative rail voltages can be a combination of either three. Yes, I can use resistors to make voltage dividers at the output.

Comment: I am only supposed to get one or the either, I cannot have two outputs. When Vin is <-8.5 or >9.5V, I'm guessing it is zero. I have updated my question with a picture of the input/output form. As long as the input and output falls under the window, it is acceptable.

Comment: Your text suggests a very easy problem with one comparator and five resistors, but your diagram suggests something else.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make two comparators. The first one is powered from +-15V. It has a window of -8.5...+9.5V with output +15V if it's in the window and -15V if not. Output of the first comparator is the positive power supply of the second comparator.

When the first outputs -15V, the second will be "powered" by -15V on the positive supply (from the 1st comp) and -15V rail on the negative side. I think some comparators will feel ok if they have input of higher voltage than both power rails, even if both power rails are at the same potential and it's effectively unpowered. *THIS NEEDS CHECKING, QUICK GOOGLING SUGGESTED IT'S !!MAYBE!! POSSIBLE*

The second comparator should have a window of -8.5V to -2V, so it outputs HIGH when within that range. It outputs 15V in that case, if it's in the other half, it outputs -15V. Now you need to convert it into 6V and -3V outputs, which, I think, is impossible without extra circuitry. I even tried to draw some circuits on paper now. If you can use external circuitry to scale down 30V output swing to 9V output swing and then offset it by 3V down, then you win. Can't make up anything else on the spot, but maybe it will inspire some interesting circuit idea.

Comment: He can use voltage divider on the output

Comment: You're welcome to make +6V and -3V. It's asymmetric. I tried on paper. I can't make a voltage divider that will produce 6V and -3V asymmetric output with +15V or -15V symmetric input. But go ahead, I could have missed something (and it's past midnight here, not the best time to make up circuits)

Comment: maybe if you have a long resistor ladder on the output powered bypower rails -15V, +15V or 0V somehere, and you have comparator 2 output attached somewhere in the middle, not symmetrically, maybe there is a way to produce desired outputs between a pair of resistors inside that ladder. I would try to go down that lane